# How to automatically redirect the user to the menu intent in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created a chat on Dialogflow that has the menu, and with each user choice, he is taken to another sub intention, but in the sub intention I give the answer and, at the same time, I ask a question, after he answers the question I I would like it to automatically return to the home menu.

I tried to find some way to do it. I researched AI, but nothing worked.